# Proving the connectedness of a connected surface deleting a proper closed disc

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $S$ be a connected surface. Pick $x\in S$, then by definition there exists an open neighborhood $U_x\ni x$ of $S$ homeomorphic to an open disc $D(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

To exclude the case $S=\overline{U_x}$ mentioned in the comment, we consider the homeomorphic image $Z_x$ of $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$, which must be compact in the Hausdorff space $S$ so closed in $S$.

Moreover $D(0,1/2)$ is homeromorphic to the interior of $Z_x$ in $U_x$ which is the same as the interior of $Z_x$ in $S$ since $U_x$ is open. The boundary of $Z_x$ in $U_x$ (resp. in $S$) equals $Z_x$ deleting the interior of $Z_x$ in $U_x$ (resp. in $S$), so they agree too.

Can we show that $\stackrel{\circ}{Z_x}$ and ${Z_x}^c$ are the two connected components of $(\partial Z_x)^c$?

Comment: Take $S$ to be a sphere and $U_x$ to be the complement of a point. Then this doesn't work. You should probably at least assume the embedding of the open disc extends to the closed disc. I'm not sure if that is sufficient, but it would certainly be sufficient to assume the embedding extends to an even larger open disc containing that closed disc.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks I have editted the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, the hypotheses as stated now should make it clear that both subsets are open and non-empty. So it suffices to show both are connected. For the part that's a disc, this is clear. For the other part, convince yourself that $U_x\setminus\overline{Z_x}$ is path-connected and use this to prove that $Z_x^c$ is path-connected by taking a path in $S$  and modifying it so that it misses $\overline{Z_x}$ (recall connected and path-connected are equivalent for manifolds).

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks a lot! That answers my question. Do you want to write an answer for that? Or I can do it.

Comment: If you're willing to write an answer yourself, I think that'd be the best practice.  I'll be sure to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifolds are locally path-connected and the properties of being manifolds and being locally path-connected are both preserved by open subsets. For a locally path-connected space $X$, it is connected if and only if it is path-connected.

So $S$ is path-connected. By construction, $\stackrel{\circ}{Z_x}$ and $Z_x^c$ are both non-empty open in $S$. It suffices to show both of them are path-connected.

The former one is a homeomorphic image of an open disc which is clearly path-connected, so it is path-connected.

For the latter, pick distinct $y,z\in Z_x^c$, as $S$ is path-connected, there exists a continuous map $P:[0,1]\to S$ s.t. $P(0)=y,P(1)=z$. If $P^{-1}(Z_x)=\emptyset$ then $P$ factors through $Z_x^c\hookrightarrow S$ so it is a path joining $y$ and $z$ in $Z_x^c$.

If $P^{-1}(Z_x)\neq \emptyset$, then $P^{-1}(Z_x)$ is a proper closed subset of $[0,1]$ contained in $(0,1)$. Let
$$s:=\inf{P^{-1}(Z_x)},t:=\sup {P^{-1}(Z_x)},$$
we must have $s\leq t$ in $P^{-1}(Z_x)$ by closureness of $P^{-1}(Z_x)$. In particular $s,t\notin \{0,1\}$. By continuity of $P$, there exists $\epsilon_s,\epsilon_t>0$ s.t.
$$P((s-\epsilon_s,s+\epsilon_s)),P((t-\epsilon_t,t+\epsilon_t))\subset U_x$$
Hence $P(s-\frac{\epsilon_s}{2}),P(t+\frac{\epsilon_t}{2})\in U_x\backslash Z_x$. Clearly $U_x\backslash Z_x$ is a homeomorphic image of an open annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so path-connected. There exists a path $L$ joinning $P(s-\frac{\epsilon_s}{2})$ and $P(t+\frac{\epsilon_t}{2})$ in $U_x\backslash Z_x$. Thus
$$y=P(0)\stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow}P(s-\frac{\epsilon_s}{2})\stackrel{L}{\longrightarrow}P(t+\frac{\epsilon_t}{2})\stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow}P(1)=z$$
forms a path joining $y$ and $z$ in $Z_x^c$. Thus $Z_x^c$ is path-connected, the result follows.